# PHP Security for File Sharing Website

Tags: php, download, readfile, file-sharing

I am buliding a File Sharing website, and I want to ask a question about the security.
My system works like these websites: [FileFlyer](http://www.fileflyer.com), [ShareFlare](http://www.shareflare.net), and [LetItBit](http://www.letitbit.net).

When a user wants to download a file, he needs to buy a key, and then he can "unlock" the file and download it.

**The problem:** After that one user buy the key and unlock a file, he can share the download link with everyone.

**My Solution:** When the user unlocks the file, I'll insert his IP, the file ID and a generated random ID to an SQL table. The download link will be a PHP file with the download id as a GET parameter. In the download link I'll check if the user's IP matches. If it does, I'll put a `readfile` function, and the download will begin.

**My Question:** Is this enough security? If it's not - why? and one more thing - How will I deny access to the file path? For example, if the file path is `www.SITE.com/files/file.rar`, I don't Want the files to be accessable from there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments if you Dont allow directory access via httpd.conf which will avoid direct file path access will solve your issue i.e. after first person downloads and copies the static url and try to download again it wont happen since directory access has been denied

Comment: There is a limit for the passwords. You can't download more than x GB per day with one password. So I don't worry about this.

Comment: My question is if there is any way that user can share the download link after that he opened it, And then other users can download it without password

Comment: And about your answer, if user download the file with Download Manager like IDM, or jDownloader, he won't be able to pause the download and continue it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your files outside of the document root and then when a user wants to download a file you stream it through PHP with the file read functions. Does that sound reasonable?

Something like this:

```
<?php
// Remember to have path outside document root:
$filename = "/path/to/file";
header("Content-Disposition: atachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename)); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$fp=fopen($filename,"r");
print fread($fp,filesize($filename));
fclose($fp);
exit();
```